# How do I video chat in Google+?

Tags: video-conference, video-calling, google-plus

Is it possible to video chat in my Google+ circles on my Droid X?

Comment: You cannot (yet) do video chat with Google+ Hangouts on a mobile device. Google has released an updated version of Google Talk that does support video chat but only on certain devices running Android 2.3.4 (Nexus One/S). I imagine this will change. Skype also released an update to their app which allows video chat, but is once again restricted to a handful of devices. Qik is the only one that I have been able to use to do Android to Android video chat, even with my non-front-facing camera on my G2. Try Qik and pester Google/Skype to support your device.

Comment: Anybody have a better answer?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no app released from Google that will let you video chat with Google+ circles like Google+ Hangouts. [You can use Google Talk video chat on Android 2.3 Gingerbread](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/04/android-video-chat/).

**Edit**: [Vtok](http://www.vtokapp.com/) is an app that allows google talk video chat.

Comment: Specifically 2.3.4, though Honeycomb also has video chat. Also, the only phone which "officially" supports Talk's video chat feature is currently the Nexus S.